# Azure DevOps Pipeline task fails but still shows green (sucess)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Task is running on Node.

Part of the yaml file for the pipeline is:

```
steps:
  - script: |
      #!/bin/bash
      ./plan.sh
    displayName: "example deploy"
    continueOnError: false
```

Now, when sometimes the ./plan.sh script fails: but it still shows as a success (green tick) in the pipeline. See below:
[image]

How do I make it show a "failed" red cross whenever it fails?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? If not, start there. If so, did you notice the `failOnStderr` flag?

Comment: @DanielMann that flag seems to be for the Powershell yaml.. I dont think I can use that?

Comment: You can take a look of the answer I posted.

Comment: Hi mgb, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding

> set -o pipefail

In the start of the yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing now is actually calling the bash script file from PowerShell. Your way of writing it cannot capture the error message. The correct way is as follows:

**plan2.sh**

```
xxx
```

**pipeline YAML definition:**

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    bash $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/plan2.sh
  displayName: "example deploy"
  continueOnError: false
```

Successfully get the issue:

[image]

But usually, we use the bash task directly to run the bash script.

**plan.sh**

```
{ 
    xxx
    # Your code here.

} || { 
    # save log for exception 
    echo some error output here.
    exit 1
}
```

**pipeline YAML definition part:**

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash Script'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./plan.sh
```

Successfully get the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your script step to signal failure, you need to make the script as a whole return a non-0 exit code. You may need some conditional logic in your script, checking the exit code from plan.sh after it returns.